# Does $a_k$ diverges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I'm not sure, If I'm doing the convergence test correctly. From given,

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_{k}$ diverges and

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}}=2$

I have to check whether $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ diverges too?

**My solution:**

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}} = 2$

$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_{k}} = 2$ ***Can i split a series like this?*** numerator and denominator seperately?

$\\ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k} = 2 {\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_{k}} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k} \gt {\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_{k}}\\ $

**By comparison test,**

WKT,

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_{k}$ diverges $\implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ diverges too.

Comment: No, you can't. $\frac 12+\frac 12 \neq \frac {1+1}{2+2} $

Comment: ahh, common sense, got me this time too. :( Thanks @YoTengoUnLCD

Comment: Counterexample: take $a_1 = 2b_1$, and $a_k = 0$ for $k > 1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can't say anything :

- case 1 : take $b_k = n$, $a_k = \frac{\pi^2}{3} \frac{1}{n}$ : you don't have convergence of $\sum a_n$
- case 2 : take $b_k = 1$, $a_k = \frac{1}{2^{n-2}}$ : you have convergence of $\sum a_n$

Basically, as you can make $b_n$ diverge as fast as you want, $\frac{1}{b_n}$ can converge to $0$ as fast as you want,

Answer (score 1):

From the second series you get $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to_n 0$, but this merely says that $a_n =o(b_n)$. For example, if $b_n=n^3$, then $a_n=O(n)$ or $a_n=O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ can both diverge and converge with $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converging

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to approach this series?.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly no you cannot split a series like that, because $$a/b+c/d+e/f\neq \frac{a+c+e}{b+d+f}$$
Now the second comparison test says that if $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n/b_n=L\neq 0$$
Then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k$ converges. However in this case as $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}} = 2$ we get that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n/b_n=0$$ and so the second comparison test is useless to us. The purpose of this question might be to actually reinforce the limitations of the comparison test for you.